# Trying to view pdf, Doc, text, image file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want open/Preview pdf. doc, text, image files using Jquery... My web application is built using ASP.Net MVC. How can i do this?

Comment: this is the shortest question description I have seen so far. As far your question: I don't think jquery is really making a difference there.

Answer (score 7):

check this link of github its the javascript pdf viewwer you can use this in your jquery.
http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/

here are the list of pdf viewer plugin list in jquery

http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/javascriptjquery-pdf-viewer-plugins/

Here is the jQuery image viewer plugin code from jquery website it self - its the thick box plugin.

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

if you want to display pdf in your website page - in .php website page ,then you can use tcpdf php class.

here is its link check it.
http://www.tcpdf.org/

here is the link for pdfobject

http://pdfobject.com/

PDFObject embeds PDF files into HTML documents

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanx for you help.. i also need to know how to open .doc or .docx files using jQuery. My web application is built using ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty basic at the moment, but I've started building this:

http://dev.funkynerd.com/projects/jquery-pdfdoc

Comment: The linked posted 4 years ago?  Haha.  This isn't even needed anymore as your browser will just render PDFs automatically.  Unless you're using a browser from 4 years ago, in which case UPGRADE!

Comment: I don't want to browser to render my documents